# GitLab CI/CD doesn't build TypeScript project (error TS5023: Unknown compiler option <option>)

Tags: node.js, typescript, git, npm, gitlab-ci

I am trying out the GitLab CI feature on gitlab.com by trying to compile a simple hello world program written in typescript but it always fails at the tsconfig.json file.

This is the output I get from Gitlab CI (truncated the start):

```
[...]
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 1f84d1c6 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ npm install
added 2 packages, and audited 2 packages in 1s
found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npm install typescript -g
added 1 package, and audited 1 package in 2s
found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npm list
git-test@1.0.0 /builds/thallosaurus/hellogitlab
+-- tsc@1.20150623.0
`-- typescript@4.1.2
$ tsc --version
Version 4.1.2
$ npm run-script pbuild
> git-test@1.0.0 pbuild
> tsc
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'strict'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'skipLibCheck'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'forceConsistentCasingInFileNames'.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /builds/thallosaurus/hellogitlab
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c tsc
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-03T09_59_39_680Z-debug.log
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

And my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: node:15.0.1

before_script:
  - npm install

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - tsc --version
    - npm run-script pbuild
```

I even tried changing the Linefeeds in VS Code becuase I'm coding on Windows and gitlab runs on linux, but even that didn't change anything since my tsconfig.json is valid.

My package.json pbuild script is simply:

```
tsc
```

When I run tsc on my local machine it works perfectly

thanks for support

---

EDIT: here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "git-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Just a test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "pbuild": "tsc",
    "dbuild": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc --sourceMap",
    "start-win": "node build\\%npm_package_main%",
    "start-lin": "node build/${npm_package_main}"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "tsc": "^1.20150623.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: show package.json

Comment: @Anatoly edited my post to include it

Comment: What does ""tsc": "^1.20150623.0"" mean?

Comment: I ran ```npm i tsc``` to be sure gitlab actually has the typescript compiler available. It's also the version I use locally on my machine

Comment: tsc is in `typescript` package. Please remove `tsc` package

Comment: The `tsc` package is deprecated and should never, ever be used. You are pulling in an old version of the compiler, which is why you get errors about unsupported compiler options.

Comment: this did it! thanks you two!